# Problem with compiling MRDS 2008 project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, robotics-studio

Good time of the day!

I use Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio 2008 R3, Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Vista, .NET 3.5.

When I execute example *TestBench* from the book "Professional Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio" from DSS command promt - everything is OK. It works fine. But when I try to compile it in VS 2010, it shows me this error:

```
**  Error creating service. Service type:http://www.promrds.com/contracts/2007/1
0/simulatedlynxl6arm.html [08/15/2011 09:23:18][http://pc44es162:50000/construct
or]
*** Service creation failure most common reasons:
    - Service contract identifier in manifest or Create request does not match C
ontract.Identifier
    - Service references a different version of runtime assemblies
    Additional information can be found in the system debugger log.
 [08/15/2011 09:23:18][http://pc44es162:50000/manifestloader/55da59ed-5e66-4520-
8b83-495d8adc47c3]
*   Manifest load complete [08/15/2011 09:23:18][http://pc44es162:50000/manifest
loaderclient]
*** System.BadImageFormatException: Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Xna.Frame
work, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d" oder ei
ne Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit ei
nem falschen Format zu laden.
Dateiname: "Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey
Token=6d5c3888ef60e27d"
   bei ProMRDS.Simulation.JointMover.JointMoverService.Start()
   bei Microsoft.Dss.ServiceModel.DsspServiceBase.DsspServiceBase.<StartService>
d__4f.MoveNext()

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: Benutzer = VIERFORES\sergey
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Pu
blicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/sergey/Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 2008 R3/bin/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
Aufruf von Assembly : SimulationEngine, Version=2.2.76.0, Culture=neutral, Publi
cKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\Users\sergey\Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 2008 R3\bin\DssHost.exe.Config
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Users/sergey/Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 2008 R3/bin/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DLL.
ERR: Das Setup der Assembly konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden (hr = 0x8007000b).
 Die Suche wurde beendet.
 [08/15/2011 09:23:18][http://pc44es162:50000/simulatedjointmover/a3bc9769-3a1f-413b-a49a-9debd6f1e07a]
```

I would be very gratefull if somebody could help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the version of XNA installed on your computer is out of date with the version of XNA RDS 2008 expects.  I'd recommend that you install RDS 4 Beta 2 and this will download and install the matching version of XNA.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28352